# Null values in setting initial state - should I or should I not?

Tags: reactjs

In the case of say... a large form. Do you bother setting null values in getInitialState? I tend to set all my values as null in getInitialState if they can hold some sort of value that isn't boolean.

Is this some sort of anti-pattern or frowned upon? Is setting values as null in general bad? Would a false or an empty string be preferred in, say a text, input?

Comment: My opinion: I think it's fine, or even a good practice because it helps document your state (since we don't have a `propTypes` for state). Personally I use TypeScript which documents the state properties even better, so it's less helpful, but not harmful.

Comment: I usually put some kind of 'empty' value equivalent to the type that the variable should become. So `[]` if it should be a list, empty string if string, and maybe false if it's a boolean and that makes sense. This way I can always assume the correct type in my code, and don't have to check for null.

Comment: I'd say this is normal. Also you would often want to clear/reset the form and one way to do this is to have a constant that keeps this 'empty' state with all nulls. You would then return it as the initial state and use it when you need to clear the form, say when it has been submitted.